# Get whether laptop is in charging [in ACLine] or not [not in ACLine] in Windows 7?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna, kernel32

I am using **Netbeans IDE 7.4**.
I tried with the below code, but I am getting error when trying to execute. Compilation is OK.

Before starting, I have downloaded [jna-3.5.1.jar](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.5.1/jna-3.5.1.jar) and added [Right-click "Libraries" >> "Add JAR/Folder..."] in my project.

Below is the code:

```
    package battery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Battery implements Kernel32{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS batteryStatus = new Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS();
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetSystemPowerStatus(batteryStatus);

            System.out.println(batteryStatus); // Shows result of toString() method.
        }
        catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Error:\n" + ex);}
    }

    @Override
    public int GetSystemPowerStatus(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS result){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}

interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary{
    public Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);

    /**
     * @see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373232.aspx
     */
    public class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS extends Structure{
        public byte ACLineStatus;
        public byte BatteryFlag;
        public byte BatteryLifePercent;
        public byte Reserved1;
        public int BatteryLifeTime;
        public int BatteryFullLifeTime;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder(){
            ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
            fields.add("ACLineStatus");
            fields.add("BatteryFlag");
            fields.add("BatteryFullLifeTime");
            fields.add("BatteryLifePercent");
            fields.add("BatteryLifeTime");
            fields.add("Reserved1");
            return fields;
        }

        /**
         * The AC power status
         */
        public String getACLineStatusString(){
            switch (ACLineStatus){
                case (0): return "Offline";
                case (1): return "Online";
                default: return "Unknown";
            }
        }

        /**
         * The battery charge status
         */
        public String getBatteryFlagString(){
            switch (BatteryFlag){
                case (1): return "High, more than 66 percent";
                case (2): return "Low, less than 33 percent";
                case (4): return "Critical, less than five percent";
                case (8): return "Charging";
                case ((byte) 128): return "No system battery";
                default: return "Unknown";
            }
        }

        /**
         * The percentage of full battery charge remaining
         */
        public String getBatteryLifePercent(){
            return (BatteryLifePercent == (byte) 255) ? "Unknown" : BatteryLifePercent + "%";
        }

        /**
         * The number of seconds of battery life remaining
         */
        public String getBatteryLifeTime(){
            return (BatteryLifeTime == -1) ? "Unknown" : BatteryLifeTime + " seconds";
        }

        /**
         * The number of seconds of battery life when at full charge
         */
        public String getBatteryFullLifeTime(){
            return (BatteryFullLifeTime == -1) ? "Unknown" : BatteryFullLifeTime + " seconds";
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("ACLineStatus: " + getACLineStatusString() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Flag: " + getBatteryFlagString() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Life: " + getBatteryLifePercent() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Left: " + getBatteryLifeTime() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Full: " + getBatteryFullLifeTime() + "\n");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fill the structure.
     */
    public int GetSystemPowerStatus(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS result);
}
```

Below is the error encountered:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not access instance of interface battery.Kernel32 (java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.sun.jna.Native can not access a member of class battery.Kernel32 with modifiers "public static final")
```

Comment: Your `Kernel32` interface has default access (which means only members of the same package can access it).  Put it in its own class and make it public, or nest it within the `Battery` class.

Comment: Hi [technomage](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17175/technomage)

Thank you for your comment. But I tried doing the way you told me to do still its not working. Can you show me the code how it can be done???

Comment: Update your question according to the changes you've made